# Get the current frame in a Frame Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to check the current frame in a Frame Animated ImageView, but I don't see a way how. I cannot find a method for getting the current frame, and I can't get the current image of the Imageview with getImageResource() because the resource is the current frame of the stopped animation, not the image it's self.

Any idea what I could do to find what the current frame is?

EDIT:
The solution ended up meaning writing my own Frame animation code:

To start the animation, call downDown();

To stop the Animation, set  go = false;

The boolean 'go' , the string 'most_recent', and the handler 'mHandlerDown' are declared globally.

```
mHandler = new Handler();
private void downDown(){
    if(go ==true){
        Runnable updateTask = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {  
               ImageView lid = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lid); // the Imageview that will be animated
               if (most_recent =="l1"){ //this loop checks the most recent frame updates with the next 
                   lid.setImageResource(R.drawable.l2);
                   most_recent="l2";
              } else if (most_recent =="l2"){
                   lid.setImageResource(R.drawable.l3);
                   most_recent="l3";
             } else if (most_recent =="l3"){
               lid.setImageResource(R.drawable.l4);
               most_recent="l4";
             } else if (most_recent =="l4"){
               lid.setImageResource(R.drawable.l5);
               most_recent="l5";
          } else if (most_recent =="l5"){
               lid.setImageResource(R.drawable.l6);
               most_recent="l6";
         } else if (most_recent =="l6"){
               lid.setImageResource(R.drawable.l7);
               most_recent="l7";
         } else if (most_recent =="l7"){
           lid.setImageResource(R.drawable.l8);
           most_recent="l8";
      } else if (most_recent =="l8"){
           lid.setImageResource(R.drawable.l9);
           most_recent="l9";
     } else if (most_recent =="l9"){
           lid.setImageResource(R.drawable.l10);
           most_recent="l10";
    } else if (most_recent =="l10"){
           lid.setImageResource(R.drawable.l11);
           most_recent="l11";
      } else if (most_recent =="l11"){
           lid.setImageResource(R.drawable.l12);
           most_recent="l12";
     }else if (most_recent == "l12"){
         lid.setImageResource(R.drawable.l13);
           most_recent="l13"; 
     }
            downDownCall();  

           }
     };
            mHandlerDown.removeCallbacks(updatetask);
            mHandlerDown.postDelayed(updateTask, 40);

}
}
private void downDownCall(){
    if(go== true){
        downDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. The animation is done internally by the ImageView class, and I haven't seen a method in ImageView class that would return you what you are looking for.